# RPLY Invalid Token Error Ever Since Adding Print

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

So I'm making a simple toy language using python, and I'm getting the following error in my code:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/ParserAndLexer/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    result = parser.parse(lexer.lex(command)).eval()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\rply\parser.py", line 60, in parse
    self.error_handler(lookahead)
  File "e:\ParserAndLexer\main_parser.py", line 46, in error_handle
    raise ValueError(f"Invalid token {token}")
ValueError: Invalid token Token('INTEGER', '5')
```

This error has only started happening ever since I added a print statement to my parser, my code was working fine until then. I was using it as the following

```py
print(parser.parse(lexer.lex('5 + 5')).eval())
```

When I use the print statement, I get the following output.

```py
print(parser.parse(lexer.lex('print(5 + 5)')).eval())

>>> 10
>>> None
```

I don't know where the None is coming from. My code is in [this paste](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/ifuwepalon.py).

Comment: Please include your code in the question rather than referring to an external resource which might stop working in the future.

Comment: Alright, sorry, I'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your question a bit hard to follow.  First you say that the parse throws an exception, and then you show the parse working as expected (except that you apparently didn't expect the print function to print its argument).

But I guess you mean that when you modify the grammar to include a `print` statement, it throws errors on previously accepted inputs.

To start with the second question: `None` is the value returned by the `eval` method of the AST returned by `parser.parse`. Before returning, `eval` implemented the `print` statement by printing the argument. `None`  is then printed because you print the value returned by the `eval` method. (You might want to suppress printing `None` instead of printing whatever eval returns.)

If you mean that the new grammar doesn't accept what the old grammar accepted, that is  presumably because the old grammar accepted an expression as an input. Maybe the original first rule was `Program : expression` or maybe the first rule was a rule for the `expression` non-terminal. Hard to say without seeing the old grammar as well. But clearly, your new grammar specifies `Program` as the start symbol, and `Program` only matches an input which starts with the token `print`. If the first token is something else, such as the integer 5, you can expect a syntax error to be produced because there is no production for `Program` which applies.

If you want the generated parser to accept either a `print` statement or a simple expression, you'll need to add a production which allows that.

Comment: OH, alright, thanks a lot, this was really helpful, appreciate it.